# distribute x number of events to users using python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that goes something like this:

```
event_name, percent
A, 20%
B, 30%
C, 20%
D, 30%
```

and then I have a pool of 1000 profiles. What is the most efficent way to assign EVENT A to 20% of profiles, EVENT b to 30% of profiles. Each profile can get assigned only one event.

My problem is actually a bit bigger. i have a large pool of profiles, and some events can get assigned only to certain profile (based on foreign key) but I'm having problem only distributing above data, for finding only suitable profiles I use merge on common column

Comment: The percentages don't even get added to a 100.. 20 + 30 + 20 + 50 = 120!..

Comment: thanks for noticing that I wasn't paying attention to the numbers... I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with `numpy`

```
probs = df.percent / df.percent.sum()
np.random.choice(df.event_name, size=profiles.shape[0], p=probs)
```

Code not tested, but should work.

Comment: I wanted to use something like this, but the problem is that a profile can get assigned to many different events using your solution unless I'm understanding your code worng.

Comment: Ah yeah, I didn't read the question properly. Let me have a think.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do it. I think your best bet would to assign them hierarchically by doing the ones with constraints first and then the ones without.

Comment: I can code the soltuion using for loops and some magic without problems.... But my datasets are so large that without using builtin pandas function everything computes waay too slow. if it helps i can show my solution using loops if it would help.... 
I have around 7 milions profiles, and around 200k events... those profiles and events then get merged together based on same key etc....a giant clusterfuck...

Comment: I was thinking using groupby and then somehow reduce number of suitable profiles every run...

Answer (score 0):

Find the total number of profiles to be allocated

```
n = profiles.shape[0]
```

Find the probabilities for each event

```
df['probs'] = df['percent']/df['percent'].sum()
```

Then for each event create a list with the corresponding number of profiles

```
dict_values = df.to_dict(orient='list')
all_events = [[el[0]] * int(el[1] * n) for el in zip(dict_values['event_name'], dict_values['probs'])]
```

Now flatten the list and shuffle so that you get a random distribution for the events

```
from random import shuffle
all_events = [item for sublist in all_events for item in sublist]
shuffle(all_events)
```

For 10 profiles and two events you get something like this

```
['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
```

Comment: mind explaining what how does 3rd step work? and what does it mean to flatten the list

Comment: First it converts the dataframe into a dict of the form `{col: [list_of_values]}`. The second part takes the event column (`el[0]`) and creates a list with that `event_name` and `prob * n` elements (prob here is `el[1]`). For example if `A` has 20% probability and there are 100 profiles it creates a list of 20 `A`s. Finally, the `all_events` will be a list of lists of the form `[['A','A','A'],['B','B'], etc]`. To flatten the list means to transform it into 1D of the form `['A','A','A','B','B', etc]`.